# How do I ensure a Java Object is of type Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, collections, casting, type-erasure

Short, at-a-glance summary of question (TLDR): how do I ensure a Java `Object` is of type `Map<String, Object>`?

---

I have a YAML document as a `String`. I create the YAML using SnakeYAML from a `Map<String, Object>` but it could be tampered with before I read it back again. I don't want to resort to PKI signing, it's enough to see whether the YAML representation is still a `Map<String, Object>`, even if the `Object` values may be all over the place. I care about *type*, not content.

So: how do I ensure an `Object` is indeed of type `Map<String, Object>`?

Here's how I am trying to circumvent the various SuppressWarnings of type erasure:

```
Object yamlObject = yaml.load(someYamlDocumentAsString);
// I only want to proceed if this YAML object is a Map<String, Object>
if ((yamlObject instanceof Map<?, ?>)) {
  Map<?, ?> propertyMap = (Map<?, ?>) yamlObject;
  for (Entry<?, ?> propertyEntry : propertyMap.entrySet()) {
    // I am checking each key and throwing if it's not a "String"
    Object propertyKey = propertyEntry.getKey();
    if (!(propertyKey instanceof CharSequence)) {
      throw new BananaException("FIXME"); // FIXME
    }
  }
} else {
  throw new CoconutException("FIXME"); // FIXME
}
```

### Can the above be done better?

Incidentally, I don't suppose Java has something akin to C#'s `as` keyword (from MSDN: The `as` operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.)?

---

After the code above, can I safely suppress warnings for this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, Object> aBeautifulAndCozyMap = (Map<String, Object>) propertyMap;
```

Comment: I don't believe I've ever heard of a better exception than `CoconutException`, although it sounds almost as painful to catch as the dreaded `PineappleException`.

Comment: Not the worst of spiky fruit. Imaging catching a huge litchi!

Comment: A well thrown PineconeException (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conifer_cone) can leave a welt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of type erasure, information is not known at runtime, so there is no other way of checking it than `instanceof`, `getClass().getName()` or `getDeclaredField("...").getGenericType().getActualTypeArguments()` things.

In my opinion you should stay with `instanceof` as it is easily readable and other developer will easily understand what you wanted to do.

*PS: I liked the exceptions ;-)*